# How do I get the value of a Cell in a GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have review various questions here, regarding this, however I still cannot get this to work.

I have a grid view (`OrderList`) and in this gridview I have a column with a button to simply update a particular field (basically mark an order as accepted).

In the aspx file I have the following code

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonToAcceptOrder" runat="server" Text="Accept Order" CommandName="AcceptOrder" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In the code Behind file, I have the following code:

```
protected void OrderList_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.CommandName =="AcceptOrder")
     {
          // Retrieve the row index stored in the 
          // CommandArgument property. 
          int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

          // Retrieve the row that contains the button 
          // from the Rows collection.
          GridViewRow row = OrderList.Rows[index];

          Int32 oId = Int32.Parse(row.Cells[1].Text);

          //Code to Update database by order id
     }
}
```

The error is coming from `oId` telling that the input is not in the correct format.
In the first column of the gridview I am displaying the `ID` of that I require.  Whilst the other columns are showing the other details.

If you spot any problems in my code can you kindly help?

(I have previously followed this tutorial: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb907626(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb907626%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an unique id for each row, then you should be using the `DataKeyNames` property of the GridView.

```
<GridView id="OrderList" DataKeyNames="oId"... />
```

Then in your RowCommand code, access it like this:

```
Int32 oId = OrderList.DataKeys[row.DataItemIndex].Value;
```

This is much cleaner than trying to get value from a cell.

Comment: oh Have never used DataKeys, Thanks for informing me about them :)
Just a minor problem,  I am getting the 'error' as datakeys is not a method.

Comment: Updated my answer.  The `(row.DataItemIndex)` should be `[row.DataItemIndex]`.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Works fine.   By some quick debugging I realized that my code was getting the value of the second column (I dumbly forgot this).  The correct format should have been: `row.Cells[0].Text`